# how to "get" with Ruby on rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I try get 2 players from a list that i created, all I need is to get all the informations about those 2 players (name, descrption etc...) and once i have selected both, I need to be redirected to /fight path. My form doesnt work and I don't understand why.

I have the error encountered a syntax error while rendering template on line `<%= form_tag ("/fight", :method => "get") do %>`

Could someone help me please ?

Here is my view :

```
<%= form_tag ("/fight", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag :player1 %>
  <%= select_field :character, @characters.collect{|u| [u.name, u.id]} %>
  <%= label_tag :playe2 %>
  <%= select_field :character, @characters.collect{|u| [u.name, u.id]} %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Fight' %>
<% end %>
```

My pages_controller

```
def index 
  @characters = Character.all
end
```

And my routes

```
get 'fight' => 'pages#index'
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? be more specific. What happens and what should happen? Do you have any error? anything?

Comment: @arieljuod OP want to say selected players did not fight on submit

Comment: Oups sorry, i have the error : Encountered a syntax error while rendering template on my line "<%= form_tag ("/fight", :method => "get") do %>"

Comment: Edit the question instead of posting additional info in the comment section

Comment: I think you want a `submit_tag` or something instead of  `<%= form.submit 'Fight' %>`.  `form` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post and also tried with submit tag, but still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error occured due to space provided between method `form_tag` and arguments provided in brackets, it should be like,

```
form_tag("/fight", :method => "get")
```

You can also write in following manners,

```
<%= form_tag fight_path, method: "get" do %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag url: "fight", method: "get" do %>
```

Comment: That may be a "better" way to write it, but it should get the same result?... I don't understand OP's error, and I don't know why this would solve it.

Comment: Why can't you put a space between the method call and arguments ? This seems weird

Comment: @Виктор This is basic you should know, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533154/10522579)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i changed the line but now i got the error "undefined method `select_field' ", should I use select_tag instead of select_field ?

Comment: @ray Well now I do :) [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480823/why-does-white-space-affect-ruby-function-calls) another explanation on the issue if anyone else didn't know this.

Comment: Thanks ! Here is my final code "select_tag 'character_id', options_for_select(@characters.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] })" and the display is OK !